# CSS: Prevent custom scrollbar from pushing the content to the left

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make the "border-bottom" of the rows touch the right border of the container? Or do I have to use a javascript scrollbar? The example does not work in Firefox. Normally the bug that webkit-appearance is not properly supported should be fixed by now, but the scrollbar track is still displayed.

[image]

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .container {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            overflow-y: auto;
            scrollbar-width: thin;
        }

        .row {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar {
          -webkit-appearance: none;
          width: 7px;
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
          border-radius: 5px;
          background-color: #000;
          -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">Test</div>
        <div class="row">Test</div>
        <div class="row">Test</div>
        <div class="row">Test</div>
        <div class="row">Test</div>
        <div class="row">Test</div>
        <div class="row">Test</div>
        <div class="row">Test</div>
        <div class="row">Test</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Is not recommended to use ::-webkit-scrollbar because is " is non-standard" feature. Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar

Comment: @DA This feature is supported on all modern browsers except Firefox. There is a note regarding "Bug #1432935", that was fixed 4 years ago.

Comment: True, but the close status of the bug is: RESOLVED WONTFIX